# Cannot access azure storage table using SAS via c#. Works in postman and browser

Tags: c#, azure, storage, webrequest

I am trying to obtain and parse a table from azure storage.

I generated a Shared Access Signature in azure storage explorer.

If I paste the generated url into browser or postman I get the table back as xml.

However, trying to do a HttpWebRequest with the url results in

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.'

I have tried different content and accept types

```
const string url = @"https://laptopdeploymentfiles.table.core.windows.net/PaulLoginScript?st=2019-08-21T08%3A10%3A22Z&se=2019-08-22T08%3A10%3A22Z&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&tn=paulloginscript&sig=***";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Method = "GET";

var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

I have tried both

```
request.Accept = "application/xml";
```

and

```
 request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

but still get the same error.

I have also tried creating and accessing a new table with only simple data. The data accessed via the brower is valid xml, but I still get the same error from a c# app.

The solution was to use both the following contenttype and accept formats

```
  request.Accept = "application/json";
     request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use both the following contenttype and accept formats

```
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: This post should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your specific scenario and got it working by using the [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient).

Here's the code I used to get it working:

```
// Create an instance of HttpClient with the BaseAddress
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://<STORAGE_NAME>.table.core.windows.net/")
};

// Add an Accept Header to tell the service you're expecting the data in JSON format
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

// Get the actual table
var result = await client.GetAsync("<REST_OF_THE_URI");
```

When omitting the Accept-header, this code gives the error message:

> Atom format is not supported.

**EDIT**
Taken from [Query Tables - Request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables#request-headers) about the Accept header you can specify:

> Optional. Specifies the accepted content type of the response payload. Possible values are:
>
> - application/atom+xml (versions prior to 2015-12-11 only)
> - application/json;odata=nometadata
> - application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
> - application/json;odata=fullmetadata

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell your request what kind of data to expect.  Try adding this:

```
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

I've not tested, so I can't promise this will work. Let me know if it does!

**EDIT:**

Paul, I tested this code below:

```
const string url = @" -- used my own xml file in Azure Blob Storage --";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

It worked with no errors. `webResponse` was populated just fine.  I just whipped up a console app and put these 5 lines of code in it, and then stepped through in debug mode to see what would happen.

I wonder what is different about your environment?  Could you try isolating these lines of code?

**EDIT 2:**

Just a thought... are you sure the XML in your file is valid?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had already tried that but tried again to make sure. Still get the same error: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.'

Comment: Ok. Well, so much for the simple explanation! Is the error happening on this line: var webResponse = request.GetResponse();

Comment: Ok.  I'm still thinking about this. I'll do some testing and get back to you.

Comment: I think you are on the right track but the wrong attribute. GET requests do not have payloads, so the server you're communicating with might not like that you're specifying a Content-Type in the request. try request.Accept = "application/xml";

Comment: @PaulPrichard, see the edits to my answer.  It's also worth trying what Edney suggested too.

Comment: Could it be because I am trying to return an azure table? I have put just those lines in a console app and having the same trouble.

Comment: @PaulPrichard, you may be onto something.  See my Edit #2 above.  Is the content of the file valid XML?

Comment: glad we got there!  If my answer helped, can you check it as the correct answer?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, on closer inspection the content returned in the browser is valid xml. Apologies for the mis information

Comment: @EdneyHolder, I tried request.Accept = "application/xml", and same error.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston the data in azure is not in xml format, it is a table. The returned data via the link in a browser is in xml and it is valid xml

Comment: @PaulPrichard, the code seems to be correct. There is something else going on here, outside of these 5 lines of code.  Without access to your actual link, our hands are a bit tied.